# Hide information box forever after close with jquery, ajax, php, mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I am wondering the best way to go about this and thought I'd get some input.

I have information boxes with close buttons on them. I am currently using jquery to hide the boxes.

The problem is, if the user closes the information box, I would like the box to stay closed forever.

I imagine I need to set up a table in the database to know whether to show the div or not. I would also like to use AJAX on the click of the close button to send the data to the database.

Would this be the best solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

- tag each div with a specific class
- $('div.class').live('click', fncAddClick);  // this is in case you do lazy load
- function fncAddClick(e) will call an ajax function to to mark it for deletion, then after the ajax is done on .success(), have it remove the div.

Comment: give them a unique id instead of a class, the parsing is much faster ;)

Comment: @Cystack - If you give a unqiue id the live will not help. You will have to attach the click handler for each element.

Comment: true but it's jsut best practice to add an event handler to each new element when needed... up to you, more coding or less performance ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you click on close button on the information boxes, they just hide from browser but not removed from html dom element.

If you want to remove permanently from html dom then you have to use following code..

If the information box id is "**informationBox**" then it will accomplished by

**$("#informationBox").remove();**

Try this, hope this will help..